# Are Firebase Realtime Databse downloads counted when listening for value changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm listening for value changed on my Firebase Realtime Database and automatically retrieving the snapshot if the data did change. When I check the usages on firebase though, I still get 0 downloads. My question is wouldn't these listenings still account for the monthly downloads database quota or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I just had to wait for the data to get updated.